# View model format decimal ? remove value after decimal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, viewmodel

I am using below atrribute to format numbers (appending commas in values). Now i want to remove zero after decimal. how i can achieve the same with below property.

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
  public decimal? Y01Amount { get; set; }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n0}")]
```

With above attribute both cases can be achieved in single DisplayFormat

Answer (score 0):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
```

Comment: I cannot apply two attributes on same property. i want to have single property covering both the cases.